# Find Text from content then hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, text

I am trying hide `specific` Text elements from content by jquery.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="name">
Trying hide specific Text elements from content.
</div>
```

I want this:

```
<div id="name">
Trying hide <p style="display: none;">specific</p> Text elements from content.
</div>
```

Or any others simple solution by jquery?

Comment: <p style="display:none">

Comment: typo mistake, now edited,

Comment: what was the issue you faced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

somthing simple like

```
var nameText = $('#name').text();
var newText = nameText.replace('specific','<p style="display:none">specific</p>');
$('#name').html(newText) // use html() here, not text()
```

Answer (score 1):

add an id to your p tag and you can hide it by jquery like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#p-id").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I make function for you

```
function hideIt(elem, exclude){
  var text = elem[0].innerText;
  var exculude = exclude;
  var match = text.match(exclude);

  if(match === null){
    console.log('no match founded')
  }
  else{
    for(var i =0 ; i<match.length; i++){
        elem[0].innerText = text.replace(match[i],"")
    }
  }

}
hideIt($('#name'),'specific');
```

place 1rst param your elem with jquery selector and on 2nd parm the string want to kill

https://jsfiddle.net/xps4553m/5/ for you